# Setting executable file permissions with automake

Tags: makefile, file-permissions, automake, chmod

I'm trying to figure out how to have automake change the file permissions on a newly generated executable automatically.  Essentially, I want it to perform a 'chmod' every time it creates the executable, but I can't find anything that allows me to specify arbitrary shell commands after compilation.  Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,
Kyle

Answer (score 2):

If you use the standard variables such as `bin_PROGRAMS` and `bin_SCRIPTS`, the installed files should be made executable automatically.  For other uses you could use a hook target such as `install-exec-hook` or `install-data-hook`.  This is described in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending) and in the [autobook](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_108.html).